# Client can't see images on my website on any of the computers in his office

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

This issue's driving me mad. I got a client calling me since yesterday saying he can't see the images on the website. He claims he's tried it on 3 different systems, his browsers are set up correctly to show images (verified with team viewer), couldn't see any plug-ins that would indicate that they block images and it seems images on other websites work for him.

All our other clients can see pictures and our testers say they've only encountered such issues when the images are disabled from the browsers' settings (but as I said browsers are set up to display images).

What could be the reason for aparently his whole office not being able to see our images on any browser (Tried IE, Firefox, Chrome)? I'm totally out of ideas right now (well i do have some but none that i can try remotely).

I've come closer to what may be the problem. I used firebug to check out the links and the image sources are wrong in some places. the src is set to

```
crm/imagini/col_st_b_editare_1.gif
```

in the code, but firebug shows it as

```
crm/ajax/crm/imagini/col_st_b_editare_1.gif
```

Also, for some reason (probably a proxy or a modem, i don't know) their browser adds 1.1.1.3/bw/ in front of our domain name in all the links and sources.

It seems to be a problem with the way in which the paths are interpreted but I can't figure out where or why it's done that way.

Also note that all the other images on the site use the same system for source paths (using the path from index.php to the image) but it only seems to break up for the images in /crm/imagini

Answer (score 1):

It might be that Watch guard has blocked images in the office. The same happened to me. In my office i could not see images on telerik grid. I mean to say that filter images could not be seen in my office. This is issue related to how you intranet security is configured.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case, as after checking further, some images work even for our website. I've edited the OP with updated information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be centered around the fact that they used a mobile modem that screwed up the paths. I don't see how I could fix it except by entering the absolute path to each image.